# how to set multiple locales in reverse geocoding with BazingaGeocoderBundle?

Tags: google-maps, symfony, locale, reverse-geocoding

I am using BazingaGeocoderBundle in reverse geocoding the (X,Y) coordinates. Since, my website is bilingual, I do need to make reverse geocoding twice.

Unfortunately, the configuration of BazingaGeocoderBundle allows you to set only one locale as it is seen in the code below. So, I am wondering if it is possible to set the `locale` while coding (not in the config.yml)?

```
bazinga_geocoder: 
    providers:
        google_maps:
            locale:               fr_FR
            region:               ~
            use_ssl:              false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to make translation with the [library](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder) by setting the locale as shown [here](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Geocoder/Provider/AbstractProvider.php#L87.).

This is an example code for that:

```
    $geocoder = new \Geocoder\Geocoder();
    $adapter = new \Geocoder\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
    $chain = new \Geocoder\Provider\ChainProvider(array(
        new \Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider($adapter, 'fr_FR'),
    ));
    $geocoder->registerProvider($chain);

    $result = $geocoder->reverse(48.79084170157100,2.42479377175290);
```

Hope it will help others ;)